# In Canada, how much soy for human consumption is GMO?

Tags: statistics, soy, shopping, canada

The first genetically-modified soybean was introduced two decades ago, and now upwards of 80% of soy cultivated around the world is GMO. We know that approximately 70% of soy currently produced is fed to livestock, mostly in the form of soybean meal, and a fairly small portion is used for human foods.

Vegetarians and vegans often consume a high amount of soy, and may desire to avoid GM foods either for concern about the environment or personal health.

In Canada, non-GMO foods can be recognized when they are labelled as either organic or certified non-GMO by the Non-GMO project.

[image]

So, how wary should we be as consumers? Has GMO soy infiltrated almost every product on supermarket shelves, or is it a rare find in specific foods?

The ideal answer would describe the prevalence of GMO soy among both soy-based products (eg. tofu, tempeh, soy milk, TVP) and non-soy-based products that include soy as an ingredient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The great majority of soy-derived foods available for sale in Canada are non-GMO.

#### Soy Milk

The following brands produce soy milk for sale in Canada and have publicly committed to using 100% non-GMO soybeans: [Sunrise](https://www.sunrise-soya.com/about-us/), [Silk](https://silk.com/our-story/non-gmo), [Natur-a](http://natura.ca/faqBiologique.php), [So Nice](https://sonice.ca/faq/), [Eden Foods](https://www.edenfoods.com/articles/view.php?articles_id=183), [Vitasoy](http://www.vitasoy.com/we-are-different/), [Earth's Own](http://www.earthsown.com/so-nice.htm), [So Good](https://sogoodbeverage.com/fresh-answers/), and [Dream Plant Based](http://www.dreamplantbased.com/about-us/faq/).

I was not able to confirm that all PC brand (President's Choice) soy beverages use non-GMO beans. They have two product lines, "PC Blue Menu" and "PC Organics" and only PC Organics is confirmed to be non-GMO.

### Meat Alternatives

The following brands producing meat alternatives have publicly committed to using only non-GMO soybeans in 100% of their products: [Tofurky](https://tofurky.com/faqs/), [Gardein](https://www.gardein.com/faq/), [Sunrise](https://www.sunrise-soya.com/about-us/), [Field Roast](http://fieldroast.com/faq/), [Sol Cuisine](https://solcuisine.com/about/), [Wholly Veggie](http://www.whollyveggie.com/), [Big Mountain Foods](http://bigmountainfoods.com/veggie-patty/), [Gusta Foods](http://gustafoods.com/en/products/), [Bob's Red Mill](https://www.bobsredmill.com/blog/featured-articles/update-our-non-gmo-pledge/), [Lightlife](https://lightlife.com/news/state-non-gmo).

Some brands have non-GMO options but I couldn't find a public commitment to using non-GMO soybeans across the whole product line: [Yves](https://www.nongmoproject.org/find-non-gmo/verified-products/results/?keyword=yves), [VG Gourmet](http://vggourmet.com/), [Uptons Naturals](http://www.uptonsnaturals.com/).